# Closing a Scanner that reads a String

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have this code (i can be very large):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100_000_000; i++)  {
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner("Some String");
  //do some stuff with the scanner
  scanner.close(); //needed?
}
```

Is it necessary to call the `.close()` method in this case or not? From the performance/resources point of view.

Comment: why are you creating a scanner at all? You aren't doing anything with it. - Since you're reading from a String, which doesn't need closing, it shouldn't help for you to call `close` on the scanner. - However, as the duplicate below points out, it's not a bad idea to get in the habit of always closing a scanner, by doing so even when you don't have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Scanner` uses `StringReader` to read the input string

This is what a possible `StringReader.close()` implementation will look like

```
    public void close() {
        str = null;
    }
```

Any `read` call after `close` will throw exception.

So from, performance perspective, unless the reference has a large string and stays in sight of live threads for longer duration, it should be minimal.

But, if the code relies on message passing(by triggering exception) using the shared instance of `Scanner` to some other parts of code(say, a code flow not be checking for `-1` and still repeatedly calling `read` on a shared instance), then it will have a different behavior